# index.php error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php, parsing

server PHP version is 5.4.43

The complete error reads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `'<'`, expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or `'{'` or `'$'` in `/home/public_html/index.php on line 40`

Here is entire code of index.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

/**
 * Define the application's minimum supported PHP version as a constant so it can be referenced within the application.
 */
define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '5.3.10');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP, '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP ' . JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP . ' or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->
<p>mark('afterLoad') : null;

  // Instantiate the application.
  $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

  // Execute the application.
  $app->execute();</p>
```

Comment: welcome to SO please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What you meant by JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->
**<p>mark( 'afterLoad' ) : null;**?

Comment: it seems you are missing the php tags?

Comment: Umm. It's just one big syntax error. You're mixing php and html without php open and close tags

Comment: would it help to post all of index.php file?  i have not made changes lately, but just realized my website is down, so I am investigating cause

Comment: I have updated question with entire code.  please advise specifically where the error is and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing php and html on line 39/40. You cannot just put html between phpcode without the proper syntax.

Comment: can you be more specific on how to correct these two lines?

Comment: The part between the '<p>' en '</p>'. I have no fix for that, but I don't see a closing '?>' tag and the last line misses a ';'